# Remote Chrome debugging on Android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-remote-debugging

I've followed https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

and am fine up 'till "Step 2: Debug content on your Android device from your development machine."

I'm logged into the same Google account on dev and remote browsers in all cases.

I see the device w/serial number, and it displays the fact that Chrome is running on the Android device, but I do not get the Chrome version or URL entry field as shown in the screen shot.

This is Android 5.0.1, with current versions of Chrome on both the OS X 10.10.x dev machine and the Android device.

I have also tried with all combinations of Chrome/Canary on the dev machine and Chrome/Chrome Dev on the Android machine with identical results.

Thinking it might be a browser extension or something, I also put Chrome and Canary on a freshly installed OS X 10.12.x beta with no extensions etc. with identical results.

Obviously, USB debugging is on, but the device also requires me to select one of three modes for the USB anyway.  Selecting "charge only" disconnects the debugger, the other two lead to this same behaviour.

So...

A> Is there something I need to do that's not in the instructions on the above referenced page?

B> Is it possible that the carrier (TracPhone, it's a throw-away dev machine) is doing something funky at the Android level to keep this from working?

Please be gentle, this is my first Android experience so maybe I'm missing something obvious to the old hands out there.

Thanks,
ssteinerX

Comment: could you make your three modes for the USB more detail.

Comment: The choices are "Charge only" (disconnects debugger immediately), "Install Driver",  "Media device (MTP)", or "Camera (PTP)".  The last three all give this identical result when connected and Chrome is running on the device:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/3h7j8ebmdufq532/Screenshot%202017-02-07%2008.02.41.png?dl=0

Comment: The "Install Driver" did mount a volume on my Mac, but attempting to run the installation package fails with "The installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install" after going through all the motions including authorization (i.e. requesting admin privs).